# Obtain a set of N routes as a connectivity matrix of nodes (waypoints) and links between a source and a destination

Tags: java, google-maps-api-3, maps, openstreetmap

I am trying to develop a path planning algorithm that considers energy consumption as a cost function rather than the travel time (TT) or the distance. For this, given a connectivity matrix of nodes and links between a source and a destination, the energy consumption will be cumulatively estimated for each link along the route, for a set of N different routes between the source and a destination.

How can I obtain a set of N different routes with data like road grade, speed limits, traffic signs, signal lights and traffic density for each link in the route, for all the N different routes?

I am new to path planning and not sure what APIs would suit me best. I am developing the algorithm in Java.

I have looked into MapQuest Open APIs, however I could not find a way to obtain traffic information.

Answer (score 0):

With the [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) you can get several different routes for different traffic density options`trafficModel: [bestguess|pessimistic|optimistic]`, `provideRouteAlternatives`, `avoidFerries`, `avoidTolls`.

You can also get speed limit data with `Google Maps Roads API`.